# React Native Material Dropdown - How to Handling onPress event dropdown?

Tags: react-native

I have an app that needed to access different API, depending on which [dropdown](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown) user touch,

so far I'm calling an API in `componentWillMount()` to create a `Label` and `item Value` on dropdown itself :

```
api.get('MyURL')
.then((response)=> {
  var jsonResult = JSON.parse(response.data)
  var result = jsonResult.reduce((r,o)=> r.concat(...Object.values(o)),[])
  console.log(result)
  this.setState({data: result})
})
.catch((err)=>{
  console.log("axios cathing error")
  Alert.alert("failed", "Retry to retrieve from API", [{text:'OK', onPress:()=>{this.componentWillMount()}}])
  console.log(err)
})

// Rendering Dropdown

<Dropdown
  ref={(ref) => this.dropdown = ref}
  onFocus={()=>{console.log("onFocus"), console.log(index)}}
  dropdownOffset={{top:10, left:30}}
  dropdownPosition={0}
  itemCount={4}
  containerStyle={{borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:50, width:DeviceWidth*0.8, paddingLeft:DeviceWidth*0.02}}
  inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent' }}
  data={data}
  itemTextStyle={global.global.TextBold}
  valueExtractor={({value})=> value}
  onChangeText={(value)=>{this.onChangeTextPress(item.name, value, index)}}
  value={this.state.selected[item.name]}
/>
```

but I dont see any props to handling `onPress`, just `onChangeText` props declared on `readme`

and there's `onFocus` props that doesn't declared in readme to handling touch, but `onFocus` just work in case there's some item in dropdown,

there's someway to handling touch that work even there's no item in dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [react-native-material-dropdown source](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/blob/4526671144e4c7296588872819e2b6b261bd6c85/src/components/dropdown/index.js#L235-L243), `onPress` returns if `itemCount` is 0.

So the only solution is to fork the repo and move the `onFocus` call to above the `!itemCount` check (or add in a different props method to retain the current API behavior), then publish and use your own fork (or just move the module into your own project source).

Alternatively, change your design to use `[{ value: 'Loading...' }]` as the initial data, which might be better UX.

Comment: for now i just move to my project source and edit the source, but i dont know how to add a code in `!itemCount` to makes it work like `itemCount>0` may you give me a hint to make `onPress` event work even `itemCount` is 0?

Comment: you don't have to change that. Add in a props method call above it as I have suggested above.

Comment: i'm not familiar about props, I have tried to edit the `!itemCount` statement something like `if (!itemCount) { onFocus(); }` but it's going weird with the UI

Comment: ok, just cut line 241-243 and insert it at line 234 (don't change the `!itemCount` check, make sure it returns).

Comment: it's work sir, and i'm feeling so dumb about it, spending a half day to find a way, -_-, Thanks for considering my request sir